# How can I run the same tests in rspec/capybara with one parameter throgh iteration in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, iteration, capybara, declarative-authorization

I am working with rails rspec/capybara/declarative_authorization. I have to run the same test with a lot of different users:

```
 describe "Revision in root folder" do
   before do
     with_user(@guest) do
       visit revisions_path
     end
   end
   it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: auth_error_text) }
 end
...
 describe "Revision in root folder" do
   before do
     with_user(@user1) do
       visit revisions_path
     end
   end
   it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: auth_error_text) }
 end
```

The only parameter is the user calling **with_user**. Can I somehow use only one **describe** block, and iterate through an array of users, to keep my test DRY. It is important, that @guest and @user1 are created in a **before(:all)** block, so they are not available at the parsing of the spec.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
describe "Revision in root folder" do
  users = [@guest, @user1]
  users.each do |user|
    before do
      with_user(user) do
        visit revisions_path
      end
    end
    it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: auth_error_text) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thx @ted. I thought also that is so simple, but unfortunately not. Everything outside of the **before** and **it** blocks runs at reading the test spec file and that time the variables __at_guest, at_user1__ don't exist, they are created with FactoryGirl in a **before** block on a higher level. So the variable __user__ in the loop is **nil**.  So I still don't know, how to solve the problem.

Comment: @nagyt234, I see. In that case your question is a bit incorrect and therefore the answer is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

Not that much DRYer, but do you mind nesting your specs?  This way you'll be able to account for any different expected behaviour between users and guests.

```
describe "Revision in root folder" do
  context "as a guest" do
    before do
      with_user(@guest) do
        visit revisions_path
      end
    end
    it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: auth_error_text) }
  end

  context "as a user" do
    before do
      with_user(@user1) do
        visit revisions_path
      end
    end
    it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: auth_error_text) }
  end
end
```

If you end up with many more duplicate `it` statements, you could probably refactor them up into a [shared example](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolve it in following way:

```
[:user_type_1, :user_type_2].each do |user_type|
   let(:user) { create(user_type) }
   before do
     with_user(user) do
       visit revisions_path
     end
   end
   it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: auth_error_text) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern version of Rspec allows to duplicate examples without monkey-patching. Please have a look to this gist https://gist.github.com/SamMolokanov/713efc170d4ac36c5d5a16024ce633ea

different users might be provided as a `shared_context` - `user` will be available in actual tests:

```
  shared_context "Tested user" do
    let(:user) { |example| example.metadata[:user] }
  end
```

During clone, we can do

```
  USERS.each { |user| example.duplicate_with(user: user) }
```